# Xamarin forms Take Picture from Camera cropping and rotation issue

Tags: xamarin.forms

I wanted to crop the picture taken using Xamarin forms but it did not work for me on IOS, Android and Windows. Also when the picture gets saved into local storage it gets rotated, this happens when I take the picture with the front camera.

Below is my source code.

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Camera not available", "", "Cancel");
    return;
}

StoreCameraMediaOptions mediaOption = new StoreCameraMediaOptions();
mediaOption.AllowCropping = true;
mediaOption.SaveToAlbum = true;

file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOption);

if (file != null)
{
    Stream stream = null;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream = file.GetStream();
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        byteFile = null;
        byteFile = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    if (stream != null)
        stream.Dispose();

    file.Dispose();
    file = null;
}
```